# Cocoapods, fail to use pod setup and pod install

Tags: ios, macos, ssl, cocoapods

I have problem in setting up Cocoapods using command `pod setup`, with an error say `SSLRead()` fail. I have found a workaround in downloading the Specs of Cocoapods manually. However, when I need to install the library using command `pod install` in my project directory, problems regarding to SSL remains. The returns are as below:

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing AFNetworking (2.2.1)

[!] Error installing AFNetworking
[!] /usr/bin/git clone https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/Users/DavisChung/Documents/Programming/Xcode\ Projects/TapBit/Pods/AFNetworking --single-branch --depth 1 --branch 2.2.1

Cloning into '/Users/DavisChung/Documents/Programming/Xcode Projects/TapBit/Pods/AFNetworking'...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking.git/': Server aborted the SSL handshake
```

One for all, how can I resolve the problems regarding to SSL? 
My mac OS version is Yosemite 10.10.2
Thanks

Comment: Do you have a Github account? Did this get resolved?

Comment: can u post here your podfile

Answer (score 1):

After having the same issue, I have realized that my network provider decides to randomly `check if I am human`. There might be another solution, but when running from terminal, There is no additional way to response. Therefore, the network provider is that one that might cause the issue.

To that my solution was to **change network**, then re-run `pod install`. The pods did updated once I did.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your network working under proxy.For this case you need download project from github point this directory inside the podfile

```
pod 'MyPod', :local => "/Path/To/Pod"
```